# Visual Studio F# project: Can't have two folders in a file tree with the same name?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2013, project

In Visual Studio 2013, one of my projects includes:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Entity\Abstract\Entity.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Entity\HumanEntity.fs" />
    <Compile Include="State\Abstract\State.fs" />
    <Compile Include="State\Abstract\HumanState.fs" />
    <Compile Include="State\Human\HumanIdleState.fs" />
    <Compile Include="State\Human\HumanAwakenState.fs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Visual Studio chokes on this, claiming that:

`The project 'Entity.fsproj' could not be opened because opening it would cause a folder to be rendered multiple times in the solution explorer. One such problematic item is 'State\Abstract\State.fs'.`

If I change the includes like so, everything is fine:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Entity\AbstractEntity\Entity.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Entity\HumanEntity.fs" />
    <Compile Include="State\AbstractState\State.fs" />
    <Compile Include="State\AbstractState\HumanState.fs" />
    <Compile Include="State\Human\HumanIdleState.fs" />
    <Compile Include="State\Human\HumanAwakenState.fs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Is this an oversight in VS2013, or am I doing something wrong, here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately it's a limitation of F# project system in Visual Studio. A more detailed analysis could be found in [this article](http://marcinjuraszek.com/2014/03/folders-in-f-projects-how-to-do-it-what-to-avoid.html).

In the upcoming support for folder organization in [Visual F# Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/136b942e-9f2c-4c0b-8bac-86d774189cff), we have to add validation to prevent users from adding folders with duplicated name in a project using menu items (see [the code](https://github.com/fsprojects/VisualFSharpPowerTools/blob/master/src/FSharpVSPowerTools.Logic/FolderNameDialog.fs#L28) and [relevant discussion](https://github.com/fsprojects/VisualFSharpPowerTools/issues/116)). Certainly we can't prevent users doing so by editing `fsproj` files.

Perhaps you can send a suggestion to fsbugs at microsoft dot com, so that it could be fixed in an upcoming version of Visual F# Tools.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'm currently using to work around this limitation:

Say you depend on external libraries (such as Bootstrap, etc. - F# is surprisingly good at web stuff, too) that *do* organize their files into folder hierarchies that happen to have duplicate folder names.

You *can* preserve that folder structure if *you change the capitalization of folders that have the same name*.
For example, this works (and you can extend this pattern, should the folder name allow for sufficient capitalization combinations)

The following folder structure:

fonts\bootstrap...
stylesheets\bootstrap...
javascripts\bootstrap...

Can be included in an F# project like so (the Content tag is just an example, it can be None , etc.):

```
<Content Include="fonts\bootstrap\glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot" />
...
<Content Include="javascripts\Bootstrap\affix.js" />
...
<Content Include="stylesheets\BOotstrap\_alerts.scss" />
...
```

...and so on.

The relevant bit in the above sample: **b**ootstrap vs. **B**ootstrap vs. **BO**otstrap.

Everything works after that. I suppose it doesn't work well on case-sensitive file systems unless you muck with actual folder names as well.