# How to bypass Visual Studio's F# project folder limitations on Xamarin.Android?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, f#, xamarin.android

I've created a new Xamarin.Android app and added a few assets to it. Those assets are available in multiple resolutions, so I placed them in their respective `drawable-XXX`folders inside the `Resources` folder. Doing so resulted in the following error:

> The project 'XXXX.fsproj' could not be opened because opening it
>   would cause a folder to be rendered multiple times in the solution
>   explorer. One such problematic item is 'Resource\drawable-hdpi\pencil.png'

This is being caused by F#'s poor folder structure handling. I usually don't need to use folders at all in F# projects, but in this specific case it's necessary because of the way Android deals with resources. The project loads fine in Xamarin Studio, but in Visual Studio it doesn't.

The project is quite big, what means I (and other people as well) will need to add a lot of files, so manual approaches [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28361170/3465182) are of no use, for they're too time consuming.

I read the [official docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/fsharp/fsharp_support_overview/) but there's nothing there that states there's a special way to handle adding files on VS or another way to deal with this limitation. My question is: such thing exists? Can I add those files in another way so that I don't need the complex structure on VS? Will I be forced to use C# or Xamarin Studio against my will?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The references to folder files have to be listed together, they can not be interspersed with files in different location. Sort the refs and it will be fine.

EDIT, for clarity:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="folder\file1.fs" />
<Compile Include="file.fs" /> <-- this can't be between the folder files, all folder files have to be listed together
<Compile Include="folder\file2.fs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Oh, boy, that was a pretty specific one! Thanks, Eugene, you saved the day :)

Comment: Sorry, what are "references to folder files"?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the standard Visual Studio integration does not support folders in F# projects.

Your best option is to use the [Visual F# PowerTools](http://fsprojects.github.io/VisualFSharpPowerTools/). This adds some support for [folders to F# projects](http://fsprojects.github.io/VisualFSharpPowerTools/folderorganization.html) and so it may work good enough to do what you need. If it does not, then Visual F# PowerTools is an open-source project and it always welcomes contributions!

I don't know much about the Xamarin Android project types - but I guess that adding C# project which is just an empty DLL to store the resources would be a reasonable alternative too. (Then you should be able to reference this from F# and load all resources from there.)

Comment: I already have PowerTools installed and it seems it's not working in this case. As for the last part, the csproj wouldn't work because during the build phase Xamarin generates a file using those resources so they can be referenced elsewhere in code, so it needs to be in the same project. The weird thing is that Xamarin states F# and VS are supported, so this really should work. Thanks for your answer, though :)

Comment: Hmm, can you open an issue with VFPT with a specific description of the scenario that's not working? They're pretty active, and might at least give you a hint what needs to be changed in the source code to make it work!

Comment: If I had this issue, I'd probably hack together an F# script to modify the `fsproj` file and include all files in some sub-folder. After all, it's just a XML file :-). That's certainly very hacky method, but it might work until this is solved in VFPT or Xamarin.

Comment: The script is a good idea, but I'd like to avoid creating some kind of folklore in the project this early on. For a personal project I'd  do it, but for an enterprise project it may cause trouble in the future. Nevertheless, the Android template provided in VS2015 should handle folders, so I don't think the problem is with VFPT. Anyways I'll try writing this script as a palliative when I get home, it might be helpful to someone else :)

Comment: @WilliamBarbosa Is VS 2015 an option for you? AFAIK the bug is fixed in VS2015/F# 4.0 integration. The fix is https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/391.

Comment: @pad I'm actually using VS2015. Maybe my F# tools are out of date? I'll check this tonight, thanks for the hint

Comment: I'm having this problem using vs2015 update 1 and Xamarin beta channel (as of today). None of the solutions I've found so far are working for me.